# Palindrome Linked List, code is not passing the test case

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
    if head and head.next is None:
        return True
    current = head
    prev = None
    nex = None
    while current:
        nex = current.next
        current.next = prev
        prev = current
        current = nex
    while head:
        head = head.next
    if prev == head:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Code does two things.

1: It reverses the linked list

2: It checks if current linked list is_equal to the reversed linked list

However, this passed only 17 of the 26 test cases.
One that gives me confusion is it can't pass this test case `[ 0,0 ]`

What am i missing? isn't 0 == 0?

*Here is the second code that I copied from other person's submission, our idea is the same*

reverse
check if equal

```
        sol = []
        current = head
        while current:
            sol.append(current.val)
            current = current.next
        return sol == sol[::-1]
```

and this code works fine.

So what is the difference? What am i missing?

Comment: The line `if prev == head:` must probably only checks that the last and first items are equal, that's not enough to check a palindrome

Comment: Did you try to step through the code with the erroneous input? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Maybe the reason is the "val". As you know, the values 0 and 0 are same, but the "objects that contains same value (0)" are not same.

Comment: You're I approach is mistaken, once you reverse the **whole** linked list you wouldn't be able to go back and check if it's a palindrome since it's an object. Something you can do is reverse half of a list and check it with the other half. Or another easier approach is to use another data structure like a stack or a list as in the second solution and use them to check.

Comment: I wrote a solution and I want to check it. what site did you get the question from?

Comment: @Yovel leetcode